# Validate entered cell value according to a given data type

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I use an Excel macro to create new workbooks filled with data of given csv files. One column is open to user input of certain attribute values. These values must fit a datatype and a certain formatting to be accepted by another processing system, here are some examples:

- Value A: String value formatted like "@"
- Value B: Integer Value formatted "#"
- Value C: Float value formatted "#.##0,0###"
- Value D: Decimal value formatted "#.##0,0#"

Now i want to add a validation to check if a typed input value is ok for processing or has to be changed, examples:

- a String value may not be entered in a Decimal field
- negative values are not accepted for all number formatted fields

How do I set up this validation? I am quite new to VBA not shure about the best way to go. The possibilities I found so far:

1. Add a validation via Worksheet.Range.Validation, but I don't have any clue how to set up the Formula1 to check for correct values.
2. Go by Worksheet_Change, the problem here is that i create new Workbooks which apparently not contain the Worksheet_Change I wrote in my program code because it is a new workbook.

So what's the best way to go?

Comment: regex? maybe.? but I don't know any regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *Worksheet.Range.Validation* is not very save because it is not triggered if user pastes data from clipboard.

Go for Workbook_SheetChange. Implement the validation there and save the workbook as your template.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Assert (Format(Target.Value, "#.##0,0#") = Target.Value)
End Sub
```

Make sure all cells are formatted as text if you use this approch. Otherwise Target.Value will give you an interpolated value.

Then later open the template and import the cvs into it:

```
wb = Application.Workbooks.Add("path-to-template.xslm")
Application.EnableEvents = false ' You don't want to trigger change events during import
myimport(wb)
Application.EnableEvents = true
```

Comment: Worked good for me, I had to add an additional Workbook_SheetSelectionChange function with some kind of semaphore to store the original cell value to replace it if it's not valid. Thanks!

Comment: In addition: had to convert the target value by CStr() for comparison!

Answer (score 1):

You can do quite a bit with data validation on the workbook side, without VBA. For example, for Value C, you could put in the formatting (*Float value formatted "#.##0,0###"*) in the custom number format for that cell, then apply data validation to make sure only numbers are entered in a range you'd like.